# Expandable listview child not showing whole text.+android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using an expandable listview. The code is as follows and it works fine. But the problem is in a child of a group I want to put some big information, but it is not showing that. It is just showing 1 line.

```
public class list1 extends ExpandableListActivity {
private static final String NAME = "name";
   private static final String time = "time";

private static final String IS_EVEN = "IS_EVEN";

private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();

        final HashMap<String, String> info1 = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        info1.put(NAME, "information");
         groupData.add(info1);

        final HashMap<String, String> tt = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        tt.put(NAME, "time");
        groupData.add(tt);
        final HashMap<String, String> loc = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        loc.put(NAME, "Location");
        groupData.add(loc);

        List<Map<String, String>> childreninfo = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<Map<String, String>> childrentime = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<Map<String, String>> childrenloc = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

            Map<String, String> infochild = new HashMap<String, String>();
            childreninfo.add(infochild);
            infochild.put(NAME, "asnflabfbalv j;ajf;adf ;j; asjfsap sdjosdjosjdos dosjdosjdosjdos osfjsodfjsofjso osjfosjdfosjf s jsofjsojdsod jdosjdsosod jdsofjsojdfsofd jfosjdfsofjsof odjfsojfsodjosdjsod sojdosjdso djosjdosjds djsodj");

            Map<String, String> timechild = new HashMap<String, String>();
            childrentime.add(timechild);
            timechild.put(NAME, "Childtime " + 1);

            Map<String, String> locchild = new HashMap<String, String>();
            childrenloc.add(locchild);
            locchild.put(NAME, "Childloc " + 1);

        childData.add(childreninfo);
        childData.add(childrentime);
        childData.add(childrenloc);



    // Set up our adapter
    mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            groupData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            new String[] { NAME,time },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            childData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN }, 
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
            );
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
  }
}
```

in this `infochild.put();` it is putting very big information, but here it is showing only 1st line of information.

How can I fix this to show all the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2` defines [TwoLineListItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TwoLineListItem.html).

You should provide a simple layout with a single TextView instead:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
/>
```

Or you may also try using `android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1`.

Comment: @a.ch.-noi havent use ne layout file for this prog.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it is android standard layout - see edited answer

Comment: @a.ch.-i tried using      android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1 this is jus showing 2-3 lines not whole text.nd i tried definig textview but not gettng how to use it in java file?i mean insted of map i should use?n thnx for the quick reply

Comment: You should define your layout in `res/layout/your_layout.xml` file.
[See this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: @a.ch.- :) :) lol i knw how to set layout file n all but in java file textview where i wil use?insted of map?     List<TextView> childreninfo = new ArrayList<TextView>();
TextView infochild = new TextView(this);
                childreninfo.add(infochild);
                infochild.setText("sddfdfdcvxv fs s sd  sd sd  dsf sd fds "); should i use like this?it gv error  on   childData.add(childreninfo); nd dsnt wrk also

Comment: You will use `R.layout.your_layout` instead of `android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2` in the `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` constructor as **childLayout resource identifier** argument.

Comment: @a.ch.-thank u v much..it was great help..i really appriciate..it was very small thing n i was jus doing what not i dont knw..!!

Comment: JFYI, you should accept answers which solve your problem (tick the "V" at the answer).